# Segmentation fault in C++ List

Tags: c++, list, segmentation-fault

I would like to create an own List class, each node has a value (double). After I added a node to the list, I would like to get the correct length of the list (1), but it just shows me "Segmentation Error" at my Node::getNext() method.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cassert>

using namespace std;

class List{
private:
    class Node{
    public:
        Node(double value){
            this->value = value;
            this->setNext(nullptr);
        }
        Node* getNext(){
            return next;
        }
        void setNext(Node* myNode){
            this->next = myNode;
        }

    private:
        double value;
        Node* next;
    };

    Node *head;

public:
    List(){
        head = nullptr;
    }

    int length(){
        int length = 0;
        if (head == nullptr)return length;
        else{
            Node *pointer = head;
            do {
                pointer = pointer->getNext();
                length++;
            } while (pointer->getNext() != nullptr);
        }
        return length;
    }

    void pushback(double value){
        if (head == nullptr)head = new Node(value);
        else{
           lastNode()->setNext(new Node(value));
        }
    }

    Node* lastNode(){
        Node* end = head;
        while(end->getNext() != nullptr){
            end = end->getNext();
        }
        return end;
    }
};

class TestList{
public:
    void run(){
        testListConstructor();
        testAddOneNodeToList();
        //testAddSecondNodeToList();
    }

private:
    void testListConstructor(){
        List myList;
        assert(0 == myList.length());
    }

    void testAddOneNodeToList(){
        List myList;
        myList.pushback(1.5);
        assert(1 == myList.length());
    }

    void testAddSecondNodeToList(){
        List myList;
        myList.pushback(1.5);
        cout << myList.lastNode();
        myList.pushback(2.5);
        assert(2 == myList.length());
    }
};

int main(void){
    TestList tl;
    tl.run();
    cout << "Main-Function abgearbeitet" << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

What did I wrong at the getNext method? Why I get a segmentation fault?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you had been call `pointer = pointer->getNext()`, you must check whether the `pointer` is `nullptr` as the condition of your do-while clause.

or just do something like:

```
len = 0;
curr = head
while (curr != nullptr) {
    ++len;
    curr = curr.next
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You're using a nullptr here

```
Node *pointer = head;
do{
    pointer = pointer->getNext(); \\ (1)
    length++;
}while (pointer->getNext() != nullptr);
```

Becuase the value of `pointer` after (1) will be `nullptr` when you've reached the final list Node.

Comment: Thank you so much. Didnt see that mistake. I changed the do-while loop to while and now I just have to check pointer for a nullptr.